# According to Shia Islam, does Allah communicate with Iblis in a human voice, and if so whose voice is it?

Tags: allah, shiism, shaitan

[Al Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/fr/node/11201) writes that Allah spoke to the Prophet in voice of [Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) during [Mi'raj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isra_and_Mi%27raj):

> The Prophet replied, "**My Lord spoke to me with the voice of 'Ali ibn Abi Talib** and said, `O' Ahmad! I am an Entity that is not like anything else. I can not be compared to anything else and I know all the secrets of your heart. With the exception of 'Ali ibn Abi Talib, you have no other close friend. Thus, I speak to you with the voice of 'Ali ibn Abi Talib so that your heart will be at ease."

This seems to imply that a Shia belief is that Allah communicates with Prophets using human voices. The Qur'an describes Allah communicating with [Iblis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iblis), e.g.:

> [Allah] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire and created him from clay." -- [Qur'an 7:12](https://quran.com/7/12)

This motivates the question:

**Question**:  According to Shia Islam, does Allah communicate with Iblis in a human voice, and if so whose voice is it?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be diverse examinations concerning that, albeit according to my limited research/perception, I didn’t find any specific source which mentioned that Allah has spoken to Satan by human voice (or at least any specific human voice). Meanwhile I found some other probabilities/explanations about that, such as:

E.g. Allah in the Quran says Kon-FaYaKoon (be, then it will be created), whereas this is not the voice/noise that ears be able to hear it …

Or, although it is a kind of voice/noise but it can also be a type of non-material voice, and actually it can be a sort of internal voice/revelation/inspiration.

And so forth.

**Source:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa26205)
- [www.masjedaliasghar.ir](http://masjedaliasghar.ir/?p=2979)
- [www.pasokhgoo.ir/node](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/68324)